# Why is wordpress now removing form tags from the HTML editor on publish?

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg

I'm trying to insert a paypal button using their code into the HTML tab of the wordpress wysiwyg editor. When I publish and view the source code in chrome, the form tags don't show and the button action does not happen when clicked.

The form tags do remain there in wordpress, however.

Any knowledge of why these wouldn't be carrying over? I've never had this happen, and it was working last week, same code, same project.

Could it be the newest wordpress upgrade?

It's weird because another button on another page of the same site, from paypal as well, works still..

Code from paypal:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="QLFJU8MHD2XCN">
<input type="image" src="http://www.spmoh.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/donate-now.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: You probably need to show some code...

Comment: That HTML looks okay so far. Can you link to a live example? Are you perhaps inside another `<form>` with this?

Comment: not in another form, here is the link :)
http://www.spmoh.com/get-involved/donate/

Comment: Hmmm weird, not sure what is happening here. There is one stray `</div>` according to validator.w3.org but that shouldn't be causing this

Comment: Disregard what I said in my answer, it was incorrect. The `/` was not in the form tag, I didn't look closely. This must be a Wordpress specific thing then

Comment: I appreciate your help, any other ideas? :/

Comment: Not really, sorry! It's not Wordpress removing the tags, though. They are still present in the browser source code. The form gets removed *by the browser* in the DOM

Comment: whoa.. so no idea why that would be happening?

Comment: Weird stuff like this usually happens when there is an invalid nesting of elements. For example `h1` elements (that are block level elements) inside `a` ones. At a quick glance, I can't see anything on that page that could be causing it, though

Comment: OK you rock! Made me remember that when adding this code back in, paypal auto ads their 1px img, which I have jquery effecting images in the content div class, therefor removing the form tags myself :( lol THANKS!

Comment: If you want to "answer" that the dom was removing it, I would be happy to check it :)

Comment: Heh! That is an exotic cause. Will add as an answer.

Comment: Can't believe this is still an issue in 2017 - yet I'm wrestling w/this today (past few weeks). Still hoping to find some easy/simple fix. 

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777117/how-do-i-stop-visual-editor-in-wordpress-from-changing-the-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form elements are still there in the source code. I can think of two possible reasons why they are removed in the DOM view:

- Invalid nesting of elements, for example h1 elements (that are block level elements) inside a ones. At a quick glance, I can't see anything on that page that could be causing it, though
- JavaScript removing the elements afterwards (e.g. some rogue jQuery cleanup script).

Comment: I had javascript removing img wrapping parents in the content div class. Thanks!!