# How do I stop visual editor in Wordpress from changing the code?

Tags: html, wordpress, wysiwyg

Every time I switch to the visual editor in Wordpress, it changes my code (e.g Removes `<br/>`). How do I stop this?

Comment: Man this has been an issue for years ... can't believe there is no easy/simple fix. I'm also looking for a solution. In my case it's more than just <br/> tags ... p tags, span tags, etc. Why can't Wordpress just leave the code alone! Lordy so annoying. Few links from my (so far futile) research/testing:

https://pastebin.com/5PyXNtHN

Answer (score 1):

You can't in the base framework without adding some plugin.
However, if you'd like a simple break on the Visual editor side use shift-enter.